# past continuous or present continuous

Tags: grammar, tenses, continuous-aspect

I'm slightly confused, Shouldn't we stick to the past continuous in this sentence?

> The Germans began running to the town and when they realized **the Jews are escaping**, started shooting at them and 5 people died."

I would say *the Jews were escaping*, or maybe this sentence does not really affect grammar rules, which I'm concerned about.

Comment: You're right that it would be more consistent to use the past tense throughout. That said, it's not unusually, especially in creative writing, to mix tenses; I'm sure there's some linguistic or technical term for this literary technique, but I'm thinking of co stratum s like "*Emma and Sally were enjoying a quiet Sunday brunch when suddenly the a loud bang rings out... gunshots*" (ok, ok, so I shouldn't quit my day job).

Comment: The problem is that This writing is not a creative one it is just a translation of a witness's statement and according to the oryiginal version of the whole sentence this should have been written in past tense, at least to me. I think the translator didn't mean to make it Creative, he just made a mistake.

Comment: You are right, Justyna. It should be 'Jews were escaping'. Sometimes we can use Present Tense with realised to show that the thing still continues. This isn't such a case. 'were' fits better here.

Comment: The whole thing should have been written in past tense. Perhaps the original was in present tense because the rules for that language are different.

Comment: You are basically right.  And this is what the English language is famous for.

Comment: "When they realized the Jews were escaping, the Germans began running to the town and opened fire at them."

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's continuous or not; it's past, and that's the point.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be past continuous because when you say *the Jews were escaping* you are referring to past continuous. They key word here is **were**.